# Installing with pip: Recursively adding files in directory as package data

Tags: python, flask, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to write my `setup.py` to install a Flask application with `pip`. I have a large number of non-Python files to install as package data, e.g. static assets. I need to recursively include these files as there's many nested subdirectories, e.g. in `bootstrap/` in the below example:

```
myproject
├── MANIFEST.in
├── setup.py
└── myproject/
    └── app/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── static/
        |   ├── bootstrap/ (*)
        |   |   └── ...
        |   ├── some.json
        |   └── other.json
        └── templates/
            └── index.html
```

It seems like there's primarily 2 ways to do this, however I couldn't get either approach to work.

### Method 1: Use `MANIFEST.in` and `include_package_data=True`

```
# setup.py
setup_info = dict(
    ...
    include_package_data=True,
    #package_data={},
    ...
)
```

and the following in `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include myproject *.json *.html
```

followed by `pip install .` from my project root. This method doesn't install any package data files at all. In fact it seems to be ignoring my `MANIFEST.in` as I tried `graft`, `exclude` etc. and they don't seem to have an effect.

### Method 2: Use `package_data` with a custom recursive find function

```
# setup.py
EXTENSIONS = ['*.js', '*.html']

def recursive_get_package_data():
    matches = []
    THIS_FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    for ext in EXTENSIONS:
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(THIS_FILE_DIR):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ext):
                matches.append(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(root, THIS_FILE_DIR), 
                                            filename))

    return matches


setup_info = dict(
    ...
    #include_package_data=False,
    package_data = {'': recursive_get_package_data()},
    ...
}
setup(**setup_info)
```

followed by followed by `pip install .` from my project root.

This method doesn't install any package data files at all. However, if instead of using the explicit relative paths from `recursive_get_package_data()`, I use a list of the extension globs, i.e.

```
setup_info = dict(
    ...
    #include_package_data=False,
    package_data = {'': EXTENSIONS},
    ...
)
```

it's able to install only `.js` and `.html` files where I have `__init__.py`.

What am I missing? Do I need to use `include_package_data` and `package_data` simultaneously?

**Update:** I managed to get the second approach to work by removing the top level directory:

```
    THIS_FILE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    THIS_FILE_DIR = os.path.join(THIS_FILE_DIR, 'myproject')
```

and passing it as the key to:

```
    package_data = {'myproject': recursive_get_package_data()},
```

However, still no luck with `MANIFEST.in`.

Comment: [MANIFEST.in](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) is only used for **sdist**.

Comment: @Katie Could you please explain why you are doing this? What problem do you solve?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I'm packaging a Flask application with my module. The Flask application uses external `.js` libraries which may have a large number of files and arbitrary nesting in their directory layout. Manually maintaining the list of package data files is too much work so it's best to recursively search and include everything.

Comment: @phd Oh crap. :( Let me confirm this works with sdist.

Comment: @Katie ok. Are you sure that  frontend and backend in 'one bottle' is a good approach? By the way, you still need something like nginx, uwsgi, gunicorn.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Thanks for the tips. For my use case a monolithic code base is a lot easier to deploy. I'll use uwsgi and nginx for deployment when it's production ready though.

Comment: @Katie ok. How are you going to update `JS` dependencies? I think the problem with wrong deploy(easier != good).

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Probably as a gitmodule.